# Response Functions in Field Theory - Subtleties?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, semiclassical

The definitions I saw of response functions, e.g. in Landau & Lifschitz (SP Sec. 125), or in Altland & Simons (Ch.7), are given in terms of expectation values of some physical quantity $\langle x \rangle$ in response to some external force $f$. I agree that expectation values were once upon a time considered the classical analogue of a quantum operator, but is it obvious that the thing we measure in laboratory is the expectation value of $x$? Maybe the thing being measured is a different matrix element of $x$? I didn't see anyone who discusses this.

Comment: This does not really seem to be a question about response functions, but instead seems to be about the fundamentals of quantum mechanics. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're allowed to use expectation values in quantum mechanics, but they don't always have a physical interpretation. In collider physics, for example, we use S-matrix elements, not expectation values. My question is about the canonical definition of response functions in terms of expectation values.

Comment: well, i think you are confised with the definition of expectation value.  you should specify what does $$\langle x\rangle$$ means? is it $$\langle 0|x|0\rangle$$ or is it  $$Tr[exp(-\beta H)x]$$ if it is former it means that zero temperature expectation value and it is what you measure in lab, if you system is low temp ect. if you work with finite temp system you use latter.

Comment: I am willing to believe that $Tr[\exp(-\beta H)x]$ is what we measure in thermal equilibrium. In that case, $\langle 0 |x|0\rangle$ corresponds to what we would measure thermal equilibrium in the limit of zero temperature. I am worried that thermal equilibrium at zero temperature would take a very long time to reach. In particular, such a response function should be correct for a constant external force (e.g. magnetic field), but for any time-dependent force with $\hbar \omega > k_B T$, the formula $\langle 0 | x|0\rangle $ should not apply.

Comment: well it is not correct for any situation it is only correct for equilibrium, and adiabatic process. if your system is not in equilibrium or adiabatic you should use out of equilibrium stuff that is kelydish.

Comment: Great! Thank you!! Please add that to your answer and I'll give you a vote.

Answer (score 1):

well it depends on the state your system is. Assume we have a many body system and we have a magical lab and set the temperature of the system to $0K$ in that case the system will be in ground state lets denote it as $|0\rangle$. Then what we measure is
$$\langle 0|x|0\rangle$$.

Now if the system is not in ground state we can decode the system's information n density matrix $\rho$ and what you measure will be

$$\sum_n \langle n|\rho x|n\rangle$$

Now, if  the system is in equibliruim at finite temperatur $\rho=e^{-H/(K_BT)}Z^{-1}$ where $Z= \sum_n e^{-E_n/(K_BT}$.

if the system  is in another kind of state you choose $\rho$ accordingly. so in short you choose how you define the expectation value for the particuler experiment.